# PHP Post Request - Stays on the same Page

Tags: php, post, curl, request

I'm having some trouble sending a PHP Post request with cURL.

What the code should do: Go to http://www.example.com/index.php with the Post Data.

What the code does: It loads www.example.com inside the Page where I run the script. And if i try to use the website, I will get a 404 error.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/index.php';

$fields = array(
   'info1'=>'par1',
   'info2'=>'par2'
);

$postvars='';
$sep='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
   $postvars.= $sep.urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value); 
   $sep='&'; 
}


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: this is because that cURL posts a $_POST, not a $_GET (which is "by website")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);//Added this

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You see 404 every time you try to open a non-existent link from `YOUR` web site.

That is because your browser tries to open `yourwebsite.com/nicelink.php` instead of `example.com/nicelink.php`

Why does this happen?

Lets see what you do:
1) You open yourwebsite.com/script.php
2) Script loads data from the example.com and outputs it to your browser in the `yourwebsite.com` context
3) All links like `<a href="nicelink.php">nice link</a>`
 are **not related** to your browsers current opened address `yourwebsite.com`!

---

And use [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
$postvars = http_build_query( $fields );
```

instead of:

```
$postvars='';
$sep='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
   $postvars.= $sep.urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value); 
   $sep='&'; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i already knew that, but is there a way to "bypass" that. That it doesn't load the page in MY Site.

Comment: parse all links from a loaded page, change it to site.com/curlscript.php?link=parsedlink